# Identify rows which are lowering the correlation coefficient in R

Tags: r, statistics, data-science, coefficients

There is a dataset with three columns as below with few thousand rows. The correlation coefficient for the two columns (sales and orders) is 0.68.

```
  empid  sales orders
1    A5  15000     25
2   B12  13500     21
3   A23  17000     23
4   D34  16200     30
5    C2  14000     22
```

How can I get a list of 100 rows (possible outliers) that are contributing most to lowering the correlation coefficient.

Comment: Maybe it's appropriate to fit a linear model and use diagnostics from that eg https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/olsrr/vignettes/influence_measures.html. This tells you observations that have the most effect on the fit. You could fit a linear model, and look at the points closest to the fit (smallest absolute residual or smallest cooks D value).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have called your data frame "emp".

lm() will produce influence measures, and you use any of them, e.g. Cook's D, to select the most divergent lines.

```
m1<-lm(sales~orders,data=emp)
im<-as.data.frame(influence.measures(m1)$infmat)
im[order(im$cook.d,decreasing=T),][1:100,]
```